# Create a pulse train from a vector

Tags: matlab

Is there an easy way (a function or something like that) to create a pulse train from a vector in MATLAB? The vector has 1 and -1 as its values. The pulse should be the same.[image: Vevtor]
For example take the samples of this vector plotted in the above figure and make pulses like here:
[image]

Comment: This should give you a starting point: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/waveform-generation.html

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, please try to elaborate, maybe add a simple example, of what the vector is and what the end results should be.

Comment: @beaker this is useful if you want a predetermined sequence you'd like to create. I'd like custom pulse trains created by a vector.

Comment: @mpaskov I added a couple of figures to make it clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stem(vector)` is a quick and simple way to visualize pulse data. If you're looking to visualize pulses in a more continuous way (either edges or centered) you can implement either in simple for loops.

Centered:

```
vec = [0 0 1 0 0 0 -1 0]; % vector
dom = [1:length(vec)];    % domain
% plot (dom,vec)
% edge plot
der = [0 diff(vec~=0)];
for i = length(der):-1:2
   if der(i) ~= 0
      vec = [vec(1:i-1),vec(i-1:end)]
      dom = [dom(1:i),dom(i:end)]
   end
end
% plot (dom,vec)
% centered plot
width = 1
for i = length(vec)-1:-1:2
   vec = [vec(1:i-1),vec(i),vec(i),vec(i+1:end)]
   dom = [dom(1:i-1),dom(i)-width/2,dom(i)+width/2,dom(i+1:end)]
end
% plot (dom,vec)
```

[image: pulses]

Comment: Worked like a charm! However, do you know if there is a MATLAB function to do that?

Comment: Not that I've come across, most pulse examples I've seen use stem()